# Swift2 along with Swift in documentation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, documentation, tag-alias-request

I just came across [a documentation page for Swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift2), yet [a page for Swift already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift).

While it makes sense to have version tags such as `swift`, `swift2`, and `swift3` on Q&A because there are changes in each version, it does not make sense to have this on documentation. One documentation page should serve for all versions of the same language - it makes everything much easier to find.

Is there any way to merge the two together (or, just delete the Swift2 documentation page, because it doesn't have a lot of useful content in it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, and I've now done so. This link https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift2 now redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift

Comment: can you please do this for [swift3](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift3), too?

Comment: Sure, @FelixSFD - done.