# Merge Documentation for [swift3] tag with [swift]

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation, tag-alias-request

[swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) got its documentation https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift3

It is superfluous and all Swift 3 specific features are and should be added to Swift documentation.

There is currently single topic there that should be deleted, but that requires higher powers :)

Can someone please delete it and create alias for [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3) pointing to [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) documentation?

Comment: they added version support to documentation for a reason folks!

Comment: ...and [it's starting things off](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/85650) on the right foot with [blatant copy-pasting of marketing copy](https://developer.apple.com/swift/). Huzzah!

Comment: I agree; I made a [request to merge Swift 2 with Swift](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331986/2767207), which is now [tag:status-completed], so I see no reason why this shouldn't be too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, this is done.

I've left comments and/or flags on all the merged topic.